# How can I show that this strange function is continuous at irrational points?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, there exists a bijection $q: \mathbb{Z}^+ \longrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, so we can write any rational as $q(n)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Define function $g: \mathbb{Q} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \,$ as $\, g(q(n)) := 2^{-n}$, and function $f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as
$$
f(x) := \sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q}, \, r<x} g(r)
$$
Then I want to show that $f$ is continuous at a irrational point $c$, so I need to find a $\delta(\varepsilon) > 0$ such that when $c,x$ are within $\delta$ from each other, $f(c),f(x)$ are within $\varepsilon > 0$ from each other.

My attempt was to first look at $x>c$ and try to show that there is a $\delta$ such that
$$
\sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q}, \, c<r<c+\delta} g(r)
$$
gets arbitrarily small, but I just have no clue how. It doesn't seem like I have much control over this function.

A hint was that I should first show that $f_n: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$$
f_n(x) := \sum_{r \in \mathbb{Q}, \, r<c, \, g(r) \geq 2^{-n}} g(r) 
$$
is continuous at $c$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, but again, I have no idea how.

Hints are much welcomed.

Comment: For the first part, consider you want to bound the sum between $c$ and $c+\delta$ to be less than $1$. All the sum of $g(n)$ for all $n > 1$ is exactly $1/2$, so we only need to consider a $\delta$ such that $q(1)$ is not in this interval. And we can easily do that, just make the interval small enough. Do you think you could do this for $\epsilon$ instead of $1$? The idea is exactly the same

Comment: I see it now, thank you very much!

Comment: Observe that $\sum\limits_{n=k+1}^\infty2^{-n}=2^{-k}$. Thus, if I want to bound $f(x)$ to within $\varepsilon$ of $f(c)$, I compute $k=\lceil-\log_2\varepsilon\rceil+1$. Since there are only finitely many rationals that map to a value $\geq 2^{-k}$, we can find some $\delta$ such that the ball around $c$ of radius $\delta$ does not contain any of these finitely many rationals. Thus, $|f(c)-f(x)|\leq\sum\limits_{n=k+1}^\infty2^{-n}=2^{-k}\leq\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ be irrational and $\epsilon>0$.
Pick $N$ with $2^{-N}<\epsilon$.
Pick $\delta>0$ such that $(c-\delta,c+\delta)$ avoids $q(1),q(2), \ldots, q(N)$, e.g., let $\delta=\min\{|q(1)-c|,\ldots,|q(N)-c|\}$. Then
for $x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)$, $$|f(x)-f(c)|\le\sum_{n>N}g(q(n))=2^{-N}<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here is another approach assuming familiarity with uniform convergence.

For each $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, define the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_A : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ \mathbf{1}_A (x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \in A \\ 0, & x \notin A \end{cases} $$

Then we find that

$$ f(x) = \sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}} g(r)\mathbf{1}_{(r,\infty)}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \mathbf{1}_{(q(n), \infty)}(x). $$

Moreover, each summand is continuous at each point of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, and this series converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ by the Weierstrass $M$-test. Therefore $f$ is also continuous at each point of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.